# To many calls of useEffect - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I want to execute code in my `useEffect` method only when `productType` is changed,
and as soon as page loaded I can recognized console.log is executed more than 6-7 times which is what I don't want.

Here is summary of my code:

```
const [productType, setProductType] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(productType);
}, productType);
```

Idea is to execute code in this `useEffect` when `productType` changes,
I'm changing it on dropdown like this:

```
<MyDropdownComponent
  value={productType}
  onChange={e => setExportType(e.target.value)}
  width={200}
/>
```

So I'm wondering why when I load this view/template, I got like 6-7-8 `console.logs` of `null` in my console..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) Hook expects an array as second parameter. They probably have done it this way to distinguish an empty array (run effect only once) and the default (run on every render), which they could not have if they would use `arguments` directly.

You need to pass an array like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(productType);
}, [productType]);
```

Comment: thanks in a few sec I'll accept it, you might add some explanation for future readers :) why was my approach wrong etc.

Comment: I tried to reason about it, but the main reason is, that the API expects an array. And that is it.

Comment: thanks man! And what about if I wanted to execute this code in useEffect even if the productType has same value? (not changed value, for example lets set productType to value of 1, and even if it's 1 again lets execute this.. :))

Comment: They you just leave the second parameter out, and it runs on (after) every render. But if you call `setProductType` with the previous value react will not cause a render and therefore your effect will also not be called, only if some other values change. If you want to force an render you could introduce another state variable for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754459/how-could-i-execute-useeffect-even-if-value-second-param-is-same-as-previous-v/57754510?noredirect=1#comment101945769_57754510