# How could I execute useEffect even if value (second param) is same as previous value - React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When user choose product type I'm dowloading a file with products which belong to that specific type.

Here is my code:

```
const [productType, setProductType] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
 if (productType!= null) {
      exportProducts();
    }
}, productType);
```

My dropdown holds types:

```
<MyDropdownComponent
  value={productType}
  onChange={e => setProductType(e.target.value)}
  width={200}
/>
```

I want even if I choose same value twice from a dropdown to download a file again, for example I choose "Sold products", and file is downloaded, immediatly again I choose same thing from dropdown ("Sold products") I want file to be downloaded again, how could I achieve this?

I know hoooks works only if value is changed / different than previous value, than code inside useEffect will render again...

So my question is how could I call code in useEffect even if the value of second parameter is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
const [productType, setProductType] = useState(null);
const [productTypeChanges, setProductTypeChanges] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
   if (productType !== null) {
       exportProducts();
   }
}, [productTypeChanges]);
```

JSX:

```
<MyDropdownComponent
  value={productType}
  onChange={e => {
      setProductTypeChanges(productTypeChanges + 1);
      setProductType(e.target.value);
  }}
  width={200}
/>
```

If you want to make sure the render function is being called you need to change either props or state. Since your `setProductType` is called with the same value, it wont force an render. Maybe there exists a more elegant solution to this, but this is one way to solve this.

You would of course also need to make sure that `onChange` will be called when the user selects the same value again.

Alternatively you could run your `exportProducts` in `onChange` and do not use `useEffect` at all. But since the question explicitly mentions `useEffect` this would technically not be a correct answer on its own.

Comment: it's solution true, but I've did it little bit on another way .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to use useEffect in this usecase

```
const [productType, setProductType] = useState(null);

const handleChange = e => {
    e.target.value !== null && exportProducts();
    setProductType(e.target.value)
}

return (
<MyDropdownComponent
  value={productType}
  onChange={handleChange}
  width={200}
/>
)
```